# erase data-context changeset temprorary and put them back after submitchanges

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext, changeset

I'm working on a project that use one single datacontext for whole project  (let call it "**dc**"). (Please don't tell me that is risky and dc is designed to has short time life, I'm well aware of that but it is not my decision)

So I use dc to submit changes to database. But the problem is some times dc.chageSet is not clear, So when I submit my changes it submit some unwanted changes too. Is there any way to do something like this:

1- Move dc changeSet to some temporary structure on start of my function.

2- Make my changes and submit them.

3- Move back old changeSet to dc

Or should I just submit my changes on a new dc and refresh old dc?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good idea but maybe you can write stored procedures with filtering logic so calling SaveChanges on the DbContext doesn't update everything. Maybe add a "IsReadyToUpdate" property and have the stored procedure only commit changes if that property is set to true.

My money says this is more trouble than it is worth though.

You can google around, but here are some links to examples of assigning CRUD stored procedures to your DbContext mapping.

http://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2015/03/12/calling-stored-procedure-from-entity-framework-6-code-first/

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx